# Does data passed across a unix domain socket cross the kernel boundary?

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel

We're writing a proxy for a network server where instead of connecting directly over TCP, the client program will connect to a local unix domain socket to send its data, and the proxy application will then forward it over TCP.

My question is this: does the data the application sends over the unix domain socket cross the kernel boundary before the proxy receives it?  The reason I ask is that if so, we could expect to see a benefit from using splice(2).  If not, we wouldn't.

Comment: Could you describe your architecture more closely? Is the proxy meant to reside on the client host? I dont really see where the splice/tee would fit in this picture. Would it be moving data from client to proxy or from proxy to TCP?

Comment: Certainly.  The proxy and client are on the same machine. The client application would send the data with an ordinary write(2) over the unix socket.  The proxy would then pass that data on to the TCP socket to the remote server.  The question is whether I should expect the performance and RSS to be noticeably different if the proxy uses read(2) and write(2) to pull the data from the local socket and pass it to the network, compared to using splice(2) to get the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course Unix sockets go via the kernel, but your question is founded on a misconception. You wouldn't see a benefit from introducing *another* copy step via `splice`.

Comment: Given your first sentence, my mental model says "on write(), a buffer in the client is first copied into kernel space, then copied back into user space on read() in the proxy."  First, is that accurate?  If so, avoiding the second step is obviously a good thing, yes?